# same match different print with grep

Tags: grep

Got some valuable help here earlier with grep so hopefully I can get this sorted out too.

This is from Rclone log

```
Transferred:      577.080M / 577.080 MBytes, 100%, 12.660 MBytes/s, ETA 0s
Errors:                 0
Checks:                 2 / 2, 100%
Transferred:            2 / 2, 100%
Elapsed time:       45.5s
```

What I am trying to do is create a email notification with custom text. Something like "Transferred 577 MBytes, 2 files with 0 errors in 45.5 seconds @ 12,660 MBytes/s"

So for this to work I need to print the values. I tried the same way I did before without any luck. Transferred it two times in the log, how to split them to get TRF= 577.080Mbytes and TRS= 12.660 MBytes/s

```
TRF=$(grep -o 'Transferred:.*' $logfile| cut -d\   -f4)
ERR=$(grep -o 'Errors:.*' $logfile | cut -d\   -f4)
TIM=$(grep -o 'Elapsed time:.*' $logfile | cut -d\   -f3-)
TRS=$(grep -o 'Transferred:.*' $logfile | cut -d\   -f4)
```

Comment: Do you really have two lines that both start with `Transferred:` but give different information in different formats?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

**TRF**:

```
$ grep -Pom1 'Transferred:.*/ \K[^,]*' "$logfile"
577.080 MBytes
```

- `-P` enable perl-compatible regular expressions and `\K` to not include the things before `\K` in the matched output
- `-o` only output matched parts of the line
- `-m1` quit after the first matching line to exclude the second `Transferred:` line

**TRS**:

```
$ grep -Po 'Transferred:[^,]*,[^,]*, \K[^,]*' "$logfile"
12.660 MBytes/s
```

- similar to TRF: get everything following the second comma + space which is not a comma
- we don't need `-m1` here as the pattern contains more than one comma

**ERR**:

```
$ grep -Po 'Errors:[[:space:]]*\K.*' "$logfile"
0
```

- only get the digits at the end of the line, strip space characters

**TIM**:

```
$ grep -Po 'Elapsed time:[[:space:]]*\K.*' "$logfile"
45.5s
```

**Number of transferred files**: (it's the first of the two numbers)

```
$ grep -Po 'Transferred:[[:space:]]*\K[0-9]+(?= /)' "$logfile"
2
```

- `(?= /)` is a positive lookahead (PCRE) where we're looking for a space and `/`. This part is like `\K` not included in the matched output and needed to not match the first `Transferred` line.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much, just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

This approach creates the whole output line with only a single process.  Consequently, it should be much faster than using a series of grep and cut.  Also, awk is quite powerful (it does floating point math, for example) which might be useful if you later do enhancements to the output.

Try:

```
$ awk '/ETA/{mb=$2; speed=$7" "$8} /Errors/{err=$2} /Transferred/{n=$2} /Elapsed/{printf "Transferred %s, %s files with %s errors in %s @ %s\n",mb,n,err,$3,speed}' rclone.log 
Transferred 577.080M, 2 files with 0 errors in 45.5s @ 12.660 MBytes/s,
```

#### How it works

- `/ETA/{mb=$2; speed=$7" "$8}`

  If the current line contains ETA (meaning that it is the first `Transferred` line, then save the second field in `mb` and the seventh and eighth fields in `speed`.
- `/Errors/{err=$2}`

  If this line contains `Errors`, then save the second field in `err`.
- `/Transferred/{n=$2}`

  If this line contains `Transferred`, save the second field in variable `n`.
- `/Elapsed/{printf "Transferred %s, %s files with %s errors in %s @ %s\n",mb,n,err,$3,speed}'`

  Finally, when we reach a line containing `Elapsed`, print out our message.

#### Multiline Version

For those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
/ETA/{
    mb=$2
    speed=$7" "$8
}
/Errors/{
    err=$2
}
/Transferred/{
    n=$2
}
/Elapsed/{
    printf "Transferred %s, %s files with %s errors in %s @ %s\n",mb,n,err,$3,speed
}' rclone.log
```

Comment: Thank you, will test this in a script I am trying to create :)